# Why do I get an empty list after trying to scrape a webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the addresses from the following housing website: https://www.point2homes.com/CA/Real-Estate-Listings/ON/Brampton.html

Here is the code that I used

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import lxml




source=requests.get('https://www.point2homes.com/CA/Real-Estate-Listings/ON/Brampton.html')
soup=BeautifulSoup(source.text,'lxml')
match=soup.find_all('div',class_='address-container')
address=[]
for i in match:
    address.append(i.text)
```

Then, when I print address, I get an empty list. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you're getting rate limited? print out the HTML and manually inspect if it had the div

Comment: getting blocked by website protection. Looks like it notes after very first request (unless you rotate various parts of your fingerprint)

Comment: I tried Scraping with your code and got all the address in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website is blocking the webpage from being **scraped**.

It's protected by this CDN https://www.imperva.com/

I don't know of a method to get around this.

*Note: there is properly a reason why they don't allow this. I am not an expert on the law but I would check before attempting any other methods if this is even legal. Especially if you intend to use this for commercial reasons.*